# Pagination Mod Rewrite Not Working

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

Can someone please let me why my rewrite ain't working example below

If i do a non rewrite url like this

```
index.php?menu=favorites&p=1
```

It works but if i try to rewrite it like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?favorites/([0-9]?)   index.php?menu=favorites&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It won't work can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Does anyone know what is the problem?